# Get Behavior instance from Sessions?

Tags: c#, websocket, websocket-sharp

If I understand correctly, everytime there is a connection request, a Behavior instance is initialized. So I save some information to the extended Behavior class. However, now I want to Send a message to *some* connected client only (for example, behavior instance that have property `productBehavior.Type == ProductType.Main`).

How can I achieve this?

```
        foreach (var session in this.Sessions.Sessions)
        {
            // How to get the behavior instance here, so I can get the property value?
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `session` is `IWebSocketSession`, and the Behavior also implement this interface. So the `session` variable in the `foreach` is actually the `Behavior`. We only need to cast it to our Behavior:

```
    foreach (var session in this.Sessions.Sessions)
    {
        MyBehavior b = session as MyBehavior;
        // Do anything
    }
```